# How to use a single application to access resources in multiple tenants in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

My client application ( hosted on a web server which is not on Azure ), needs to access Azure Storage accounts for various Organizations.

Say there are three Organizations - Org1, Org2 and Org3. I would have one instance of my application running on my server for each of these 3 organizations, so basically they are isolated instances. There would be a UI based form for an organization to enter their details ( like subscription id, storage account name etc ).

I was under the impression that I have two options.

**Option A** - Create an app registration in each Organization. So there would be 3 apps created ( one in each of the Organization's tenant ). Each Organization would have to give their respective app's service principal a role to be able to access their Storage Accounts. So 3 apps and 3 service principals in total.

**Option B** - Create an app registration in my Organization ( tenant ). For ease of understanding let us call this SomanshOrg.
Can we create a service principal in Org 1, Org2, Org3 where each Organization would have to give their respective app's service principal a role to be able to access their Storage Accounts. And then from my client application I would be able to access their resources. So 1 app and 4 service principals ( 3 Org + mine ) in total.

The end goal is to only take credentials from the User in the initial UI form. And then we can access their Azure Storages without any more user involvement.

Which of these options would be better? Or is a different option more suitable for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which of these options would be better? Or is a different option more suitable for my use case?

Option B is better and I think it should be the most suitable way in this case.

You just need to create a [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps) in the SomanshOrg, then use the respective admin accounts of the Org1, Org2, Org3 to [consent the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) for the respective tenants.

After the consent, the service principals will locate in the respective tenants, then you just need to add the [RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) for them on the storage account scope.

The last step is to access the storage accounts, if you want to do this without any user involvement, just use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token to access the storage accounts. The advantage of option B is that we just need one application ID and one client secret([*create it in the SomanshOrg*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret)), the secret can be used for all the service principals of the app.

Comment: But I have a concern about the security. If we have just one application and multiple service principals, then I assume that with the same set of credentials ( client id and client secret ), we can access all the tenants. So it would be the responsibility of my application to ensure that organizations cannot access each other's data. My premise here is that the secret key is per application and not per service principal. Is that correct?

Comment: @SomanshReddy Yes, the secret is for the application, but it can be used for all the service principals. You can also use powershell [`New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceprincipalpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) to create secrets for each service principal, the secret is just can be used for its own service principal(the secret will not be shown in the portal).

Comment: So, when an admin consents to the app, a service principal would be automatically created in the tenant. But this service principal wouldn't have it's own password credentials at that time, I assume? 

Also, can we not create secrets for service principals via the Portal ( yes, we cannot see them anywhere but can we create them via the portal ).

Comment: @SomanshReddy 1.Yes, the service principal will not have it's own password credentials at that time. 2.You cannot create the service principal secret in the portal, you can only create it via powershell or the graph api https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http What you created in the portal is the secret of the app, it is different from the secret of the service principal. In short, the secret of the app can be used for all the related service principals, but the secret of each service principal can not be used for another one.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Let me test this out in practice and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221112/discussion-between-somansh-reddy-and-joy-wang).

Comment: Can someone elaborate a bit more on option A please ?

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin What do you want to know actually? I think what you said in the question about option A is complete, it is just like the use service principal access storage, then do the same thing in the three different for three times.

Comment: yeah i can get that, but the thing is you need to register the app on both those domains right? how do you that because the app-id is gonna be different and the tenant-id aswell?

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin So I recommend you to use option B.