# 2 Different Azure AD domains for 1 application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, windows-authentication

I am facing a kinda frustrating issue here.

I want to build an authentication architecture that contains 2 different unrelated Azure AD Domains with different tenant-Id's.

I figured out 2 different scenario's so the application can be accessed from our developer account and the client can access it from their accounts.

Scenario 1: The 2 domains works independently from each other and thus the application allows both those domains to authenticate.

[image]

Scenario 2: Our developer domain gets registered at the client domain and redirected to the application.

[image]

Now my question is: Is one of those scenarios's possible?
I allready builded a concept, but for now i need to add a developer account into the client domain Azure AD and that is not ideal.

I followed this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant) but i think this is for authenticate with personal and school/work accounts.

We want both accounts working to authenticate in one single application.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must ensure that the application is a **[multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps)**.

Then you need to use [Powershell cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0)  `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "{client id of your application}"` to add the application to these two domains as an enterprise application.

Next, you will be able to log in to the application using a different domain.

Comment: yeah i have been looking into your answer but it not that clear to me. I read some more documentation and ended up using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: is it also possible to work with these 2 in that scenario, these are 2 completely different azure domains with both their Azure AD. I cannot find much documentation about this...

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin   I haven't tried the method in the link you provided. Have you tried the answer I provided?

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin   Here is a question similar to yours, I hope it can provide you with inspiration:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756127/how-to-use-a-single-application-to-access-resources-in-multiple-tenants-in-azure/63770504#63770504